# pandas grouping by multiple categories for duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given this sample dataset, I am attempting to alert various companies that they have duplicates in our database so that they can all communicate with each other and determine which company the person belongs to:

```
Name            SSN      Company
Smith, John     1234     A
Smith, John     1234     B
Jones, Mary     4567     C
Jones, Mary     4567     D
Williams, Joe   1212     A
Williams, Joe   1212     C
```

The ideal output is a data frame provided to each company alerting them to duplicates in the data and the identity of the other company claiming the same person as assigned to them.  Something like this:

Company A dataframe

```
Name             SSN      Company
Smith, John      1234     A
Smith, John      1234     B
Williams, Joe    1212     A
Williams, Joe    1212     C
```

Company C dataframe

```
Name             SSN      Company
Jones, Mary      4567     C
Jones, Mary      4567     D
Williams, Joe    1212     A
Williams, Joe    1212     C
```

So, tried groupby ['Company'], but, of course, that only groups all the Company results in one group, it omits the other Company with the duplicate person and SSN.  Some version of groupby (deep in the logic of that one) seems like it should work, but grouping by multiple columns, not quite.  The output would be a grouped by company but containing the duplicate value associated with all the values in that company's group.  A enigma, hence my post.

Perhaps groupby Company and then concatenate each Company group with each other group on the Name column?

Comment: Why there is no company B dataframe?

Comment: @DaniMesejo. Oh, just left it out for brevity.  There will be a dataframe for every company in the result, hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we pivot on `Company` to see employees who are in multiple companies easily:

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df.assign(count = 1), index = ['Name','SSN'], columns='Company', values='count', aggfunc = 'count')
```

produces

```
    Company             A   B   C   D
Name            SSN             
Jones,Mary      4567    NaN NaN 1.0 1.0
Smith,John      1234    1.0 1.0 NaN NaN
Williams,Joe    1212    1.0 NaN 1.0 NaN
```

where values are the count of an employee in that company and NaN means he is not in it

now we can manipilate to extract useful views for different companies. For A we can say 'pull everyone who is in company A *and* in any of the other companies':

```
dfA = df2[(~df2['A'].isna()) & (~df2[['B','C','D']].isna()).any(axis=1) ].dropna(how = 'all', axis=1)
dfA
```

this produces

```
    Company              A  B   C
Name            SSN         
Smith,John      1234    1.0 1.0 NaN
Williams,Joe    1212    1.0 NaN 1.0
```

Note we dropped companies that are irrelevant here, via `dropna(...)`, in this case D, as there were no overlaps between A and D. and column D had all NaNs

We can easily write a function to produce a report for any company

```
def report_for(company_name):
    companies = df2.columns
    other_companies = [c for c in companies if c != company_name]
    return (df2[(~df2[company_name].isna()) 
              & (~df2[other_companies].isna()).any(axis=1) ]
              .loc[:,[company_name] + other_companies]
              .dropna(how = 'all', axis=1)
              )
```

Note we also re-order columns so the table for company 'B' has column 'B' first:

```
report_for('B')
```

generates

```
    Company         B   A
Name        SSN     
Smith,John  1234    1.0 1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for both the response and the details explaining it.  So much to learn here and these steps and the strategy behind them worked great.

Comment: @JohnTaylor awesome, glad it helped!

Comment: FYI I extended this one step further and replaced the 1 values with the column names so I could produce data to each company with a person and the associated company names, for each person on a row. Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnTaylor sounds like a useful addition. If you want, feel free to edit the answer to include that step